# Character operations in C

Tags: c, char, arithmetic-expressions

When you cast a character to an int in C, what exactly is happening? Since characters are one byte and ints are four, how are you able to get an integer value for a character? Is it the bit pattern that is treated as a number. Take for example the character 'A'. Is the bit pattern 01000001 (i.e 65 in binary)?

Comment: `'A'` is already an `int` in C.  Either way, `'A'` is syntax sugar for `65` (assuming an ASCII implementation).  Does that answer your question?

Comment: `char` in C is an *integer* type.

Comment: The bit pattern is always "treated as a number" - you can apply on `char` operands any of the arithmetic operations that you apply on `int` operands. It just so happen that when you sent it to the console with `printf` (or in some cases, through the debugger), you see it as a "character".

Answer (score 6):

`char` and `int` are both integer types.

When you convert a value from any arithmetic (integer or floating-point) type to another arithmetic type, the conversion preserves the *value* whenever possible. Arithmetic conversions are always defined in terms of values, not representations (though some of the rules are designed to be simply implemented on most hardware).

In your case, you might have:

```
char c = 'A';
int i = c;
```

`c` is an object of type `char` with the value `65` (assuming an ASCII representation). The conversion from `char` to `int` yields an `int` with the value `65`. The compiler generates whatever code is necessary to make that happen; in terms of representation, it could either sign-extend or pad with 0 bits.

This applies when the value of the source expression can be represented as a value of the target type. For a `char` to `int` conversion, that's (almost) always going to be the case. For some other conversions, there are various rules for what to do when the value won't fit:

- For any conversion to or from floating-point, if the value is out of range the behavior is undefined (`(int)1.0e100` may yield some arbitrary value or it can crash your program), and if it's within range but inexact it's approximated by rounding or truncation;
- For conversion of a signed or unsigned integer to an unsigned integer, the result is wrapped (`unsigned)-1 == UINT_MAX)`;
- For conversion of a signed or unsigned integer to a signed integer, the result is implementation-defined (wraparound semantics are common) -- or an implementation-defined signal can be raised.

(Floating-point conversions also have to deal with precision.)

Other than converting integers to unsigned types, you should generally avoid out-of-range conversions.

Incidentally, though `int` may happen to be 4 bytes on your system, it could be any size as long as it's able to represent values from `-32767` to `+32767`. The ranges of the various integer types, and even the number of bits in a byte, are implementation-defined (with some restrictions imposed by the standard). 8-bit bytes are almost universal. 32-bit `int` is very common, though older systems commonly had 16-bit `int` (and I've worked on systems with 64-bit `int`).

Comment: Correction: conversions between integer and floating point are well-defined as long as they fall within the range of the destination type.

Comment: @david.pfx: You're right. That's actually what I meant, but I wrote it incorrectly. I'll fix answer tomorrow or so.

Comment: Yes, I know you knew but it just didn't come out quite right.

Comment: What do you mean by sign-extend